# Can C macros be expanded in gdb when the program was compiled using clang?

Tags: c, gdb, clang, c-preprocessor

I have a macro that fetch's the J-th bit of an integer:

```
#define TWO_TO_THE(POWER) (1 << POWER)

#define JTH_BIT(BITS, J)  ((TWO_TO_THE((J-1)) & BITS) != 0)
```

However, I can't use it from gdb by issuing the command `print JTH_BIT(i,j)`, can macros in C even be used while debugging?

Comment: This should be reopened, as this is quetion is about `clang` and the assumed duplicate is about `gcc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros are handled by the pre-processor. The compiler doesn't even know about them.

However, if lucky, GCC's option `-g3` would do the job and generate code allowing `gdb` to expand a macro.

From the [gdb documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) (emphasis by me):

> -glevel
>
> [...]
>      Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions present in the program. ***Some*** debuggers support macro expansion when you use -g3.

Comment: But this question is about the debugger, not the compiler. The debugger has access to both the binary and the source (typically), so anything is possible.

Comment: I changed my makefile to compile with -g3, but when I try to print the result of the macro, I get "GDB has no preprocessor macro information for that code", do I need to load the header files in gdb?

Comment: @TobiLehman: What does `info macro JTH_BIT` tell you? And: Did you do a `make clean`?

Comment: @alk I did a `make clean` and then a `make`, and the `-g3` arg used when compiling. Then when in the debugger at a line where the macro is in scope, `info macro JTH_BIT` returns 
`GDB has no preprocessor macro information for that code.`

Comment: @TobiLehman: Which gcc are you using though, on which platform? You should perhaps test this with a simple (2 liner) example, if the version of gcc you use does support macro expansion if having used `-g3`.

Comment: I'm using gcc Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Answer (score 3):

It should work, if you compile your program with the right options. In gcc, you need to say "-g3" when you compile

See [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html) and [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compilation.html#Compilation).

Comment: I doubt that's helpful when the op is apparently using clang.